# Clojure: alternative to using a mutex/lock and a counter

Tags: networking, clojure, clojureclr

Scenario: I have a server listening to six active TCP/IP connections. When a "ready" message comes in, an event will be raised on its own thread. When the server has received a "ready" message from each connection, it needs to run the "start" function.

My object oriented solution would likely involve using a mutex and a counter. Something like:

```
int _countDown= 6;
object _lock;
void ReadyMessageReceivedForTheFirstTimeFromAConnection() {
    lock(_lock) {
      --_countDown; // 
       if (_countDown==0) Start();
    }
}
```

How could this problem be solved in Clojure without resorting to locks/mutexes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you prefer a pure clojure version, you can use a promise to give your futures a go.

Every time you receive message you increment the conn-count
the watch checks if the treshold is reached and delivers :go to the barrier promise.

```
(def wait-barrier (promise))
(def conn-count (atom 0))

(add-watch conn-count :barrier-watch
           (fn [key ref old-state new-state]
             (when (== new-state 6)
               (deliver wait-barrier :go))))
```

dummy-example:

```
(def wait-barrier (promise))
(def conn-count (atom 0))
(defn worker-dummy []
  (when (= @wait-barrier :go)
    (println "I'm a worker")))

(defn dummy-receive-msg []
  (doall (repeatedly 6,
                     (fn []
                       (println "received msg")
                       (swap! conn-count inc)))))

(let [workers (doall (repeatedly 6 (fn [] (future (worker-dummy)))))]
  (add-watch conn-count :barrier-watch
             (fn [key ref old-state new-state]
               (when (== new-state 6)
                 (deliver wait-barrier :go))))
  (dummy-receive-msg)
  (doall (map deref workers)))
```

Comment: (str "+" 1) for no interop answer. If just for learning value. BTW you don't need `(not= old-state new-state)` in the second snippet, `deliver` is a noop when it's called on an already realized promise.

Comment: you are right, I can't approve due to the lack of privileges  tough.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a CountDownLatch or a Phaser for this purpose.

In my futures library, imminent, I used both. [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) first and then replaced it with a [Phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) for ForkJoin compatibility (might not be necessary in your case). You can see the change in [this diff](https://github.com/leonardoborges/imminent/commit/d4527ebae5fa30191b3525b5cb4fd18f80ab4616#diff-afdb0709fb6f81c4999501e4fcf69af7). Hopefully it gives you an idea of usage for both.

With latches the general idea would be:

```
(let [latch (CountDownLatch. 6)]
  (on-receive-message this (fn [_] (.countDown latch)))
  (.await latch)
```

...or something like that.

Comment: Exactly this. Using a mutex and a counter is wrong in an imperative world too: find the right concurrency primitives for the job, instead of reimplementing everything on top of mutexes.

Comment: Sorry if this is dumb question, but how does Java's "this" keyword work in Clojure? Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: It's not a dumb question at all. 'this' in Clojure has no special meaning. It's just convention to use 'this' when you're implementing a protocol or an interface. The confusion in the example above is that this is defined outside the let block. That's probably what tripped you.

Answer (score 2):

Since it hasn't been mentioned so far: you could easily do that with [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async). Have a look at this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
(let [conn-count 6
      ready-chan (chan)]

  ;; Spawn a thread for each connection.
  (doseq [conn-id (range conn-count)]
    (thread
      (Thread/sleep (rand-int 2000))
      (>!! ready-chan conn-id)))

  ;; Block until all connections are established.
  (doseq [total (range 1 (inc conn-count))]
    (println (<!! ready-chan) "connected," total "overall"))

  ;; Invoke start afterwards.
  (println "start"))
;; 5 connected, 1 overall
;; 3 connected, 2 overall
;; 4 connected, 3 overall
;; 0 connected, 4 overall
;; 1 connected, 5 overall
;; 2 connected, 6 overall
;; start
;;=> nil
```

You could also use a channel to implement a countdown latch (borrowed from [Christophe Grand](https://twitter.com/cgrand/status/801377579726962688)):

```
(defn count-down-latch-chan [n]
  (chan 1 (comp (drop (dec n)) (take 1))))
```

For a short introduction into core.async, check out [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/beatngu13/076b2261d25b17e759951b2a4a2ced0d). For a longer one, read the [corresponding chapter](http://www.braveclojure.com/core-async/) in "Clojure for the Brave and True".